# What does the word, “rascally charm” mean? Can “Rascally” be used as a complimentary modifier?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

There was the following comversation in the Vanity Fair’s (November 14 issue) article that came under the title, “Imagined Celebrity Connections: How Beyoncé Responded to Kim Kardashian’s Paper Magazine Cover”

> Kate Middleton meets Harry Styles:
>
> “It’s so nice to meet you, Duchess,” Harry says, shaking Kate’s hand,
>   biting his lip. Kate laughs.
>
> “Now, are you the one who dated Taylor Swift?” Harry smiles
>   sheepishly.
>
> “Maybe?”
>
> “She saw you in trouble, right?”
>
> “Something like  that,” Harry murmurs.
>
> “You know, you remind me of another Harry I know,” she says.
>
> “You’ve got that . . . **rascally charm**.” Harry looks up, smiling
>   slightly.
>
> “So I’ve always wondered . . . do you, like, eat real food?
>
> http://www.vanityfair.com/vf-hollywood/2014/11/beyonce-kim-kardashian-paper-magazine-cover

OALED defines ‘rascally’ as an adjective of ‘rascal,’ which means a person who shows a lack of respect for other people and enjoying tricks on them.

Collins Cobuild English Dictionary defines ‘rascally person’ as a person who behaves badly and wicked or dishonest.

What does “rascally charm” mean here? 
What is a charm of a person on earth who behaves badly and wicked or dishonest to you? Is it a complementary / endearment expression, or a simple irony?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rascal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rascal) is also used with the following meaning :  (from Collins English Dictionary)

> - an affectionate or mildly reproving term for a child or old man: you little rascal; the wicked old rascal kissed her.
> - A mischievous or cheeky person, especially a child or man (typically used in an affectionate way):
>   a lovable rascal
>   you are such a rascal! (from ODO).

In the extract 'rascally'  is used is in the sense of a friendly way to refer to a person. Here the idea is of a 'fascinating, enchanting' charm.

Comment: Does it differ from "totally charm / awesomely charm" in Valley girl vernaculars? Is it more characteristic?

Comment: The word 'rascal' hints at someone who is naughty in a playful and teasing way, and that characteristics can  be very seductive when used in a charming way. I think its connotation is more powerful and intriguing than 'totally or awesomely'.